# Detect session expiration

Tags: .net

In my .net application I need to store the page that was displayed before session expiration, for example if the user was in the page A and the session expire when hi will acces to the app I have to redirect him to the page A.

My idea is to detect session expiration and if the event happen save the data in data base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the problem with javascript, the approach is to have variable that represents session timeout and in make global javascript method that declenche session Save before expiration. 
`$(document).ready(function () {
    var saveSessionTimer;
    clearTimeout(saveSessionTimer);
//timerToSaveSession = sessionExpireTime - 10 seconds
    saveSessionTimer = setTimeout(saveSession, timerToSaveSession);
});`
where saveSession is the method that call controller and make the save.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply a session variable.
On page load check if the variable exists, and if it doesn't exist anymore you can save the data you need.

You can retrieve the URL also if the session has expired.
UserId should be stored in some "permanent" place, like a hidden field in the page, so you can retrieve it also if the session has expired.

Comment: If I wait session expiration I will not be able to make the request to save data. To restore data I will test if the data is registred if so I will redirect the user

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: You can use the `Session_End` method in `global.asax` to detect an expiring session.

Unfortunately, at that time, the information about the page that the user accessed last is no longer (conveniently) available, so I doubt that this will help you solve your underlying problem.

As an alternative, I would suggest that you update the user's "last visited page" in your database every time a page is opened. You can do that globally in your master page, if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1) For each request (`Application_BeginRequest`) store in the session context data (user, URL etc.):

```
Session["LastPageData"] = new { Url = ..., };
```

2) Before session is about to end, you can use the information to store in a database, for example:

```
void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs E) {
    // do persistence logic here based on Session["LastPageData"]
}
```

If some information is not available in `Session_End`, you can persist the information on each request, but this will mean extra overhead (`INSERT`/`UPDATE` for each request)

Comment: But how to detect that the session will expire. I theink that I need to do a JavaScript timer to konw that the session will expire soon

Answer (score 0):

As you will be already knowing being a web application, the interaction between your user agent and server is disconnected i.e. web server or browser does not have information about the current state of user, so there are no event which will let you know that session has expired, though you can compute it based on session time out values and check whether the session has expired or not (or do any similar thing).

So, you can know that session has expired only when the request reached your server and the request is processed.

For solution to your problem, on session expiry you will be redirecting the user to login page, before redirection you can put the current page url relative path in the URL as a parameter and on successful login, you can redirect user to previous page by reading it from query string.

Your login url will look like this https://myapp.com/Account/Login?returnUrl=%2F**MyAccount**

Here MyAccount is the last visited URL where session has expired.

The same approach is used by asp.net MVC authorization, you may have a look at it using the default template.

Comment: I understand what you say but I still have to redirect user even if he connect from an other navigator. I think that the best choice is to save the information every time the user visit a page

Comment: Yes, then again you have store the data some where so that you can retrieve it when you detect the session expiry and that needed be specific to user. But with session expiry all the session related info will also expire, so if you store in session, you can not get it. Please let me know if you need any other info.

Answer (score 0):

you may use Session_OnEnd, Session_End() even in your global.asax file,

In this event you may save your session value into the db explicitly because Session_OnEnd and Session_End don't get called if session is out proc (Saving session in state server Or sql server).

Now when user will open the application again then on each page load you have to check the value of session variable (I'm not sure if it can be done itself into Session_Start or Apllication_Start events in global.asax) and if it is null then get the latest value from the db and redirect to respective page.

Comment: Session_OnEnd does not take into account if the user closes their browser